# Get full path to file while debugging using IIS Express

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-express, directoryinfo

I have a .NET application that I am trying to debug and part of my application loads a file from my project.  This file is located at

```
C:\Users\USER_FOLDER\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MY_PROJECT\_templates\myFile.html
```

In my code, I specify a relative path to the file and use the DirectoryInfo class to get the full directory path to my file:

```
string myFile = (new DirectoryInfo("_templates/myFile.html")).FullName;
```

However, this returns the following path (extra \'s as escape characters):

```
"C:\\Program Files\\IIS Express\\_templates\\myFile.html"
```

I was expecting the path that is returned when debugging in IIS Express would match the first path I listed, not the third.  Why is this?  Is there something else that I need to set up in my project to have it derive the paths properly?  I'm assuming that this would not happen if I deployed my code to a IIS7 site, but I haven't gotten to that testing level yet.

Comment: If its returning `Program Files\\IIS Express\\` it means your launching it from that directory path so be more specific about the directory path.  Considering `"_templates/myFile.html" would be a local directory within the parent directory its not very specific.

Comment: On that note, calling Server.MapPath returned the correct path without having to be more descriptive.  Going into this I didn't think I had to be more descriptive because as in other languages, I was treating the path as it was relative to the location of the script that was referencing the file, but in order to read its contents the .NET server needs a Fully Qualified URI to the path and I was just using the wrong Object to derive it.  Why my _valid_ question was voted down is perplexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Server.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632):

```
Server.MapPath("~/_templates/myFile.html")
```

or [HttpServerUtility.MapPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx):

```
HttpServerUtility.MapPath("~/_templates/myFile.html")
```

Comment: Thanks!  Server.MapPath worked for me, but I couldn't get HttpServerUtility.MapPath to work.  For HttpServerUtility it kept complaining that `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(string)'`  I tried various ways of writing it and nothing worked, so I'm going to just use Server.MapPath.  Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure if this is the exact same situation but I had the same object reference problem. I solved it using the HttpContext. As in - HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();